# Can I customize the ToolStrip to include Automator scripts?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, applescript, automator, touch-bar

I want to include special actions in Finder such as showing or not showing hidden files.

*most* of the time I want to have a clean clutter free system, however there are times I need to dig into the library or other system locations.

It would be nice to have a way to use the touch bar to create a clutter free Finder experience that can be enabled/disabled.

Is it possible to include scripts in the Toolbar feature of Finder or any other app?

Comment: What is the ToolStrip?

Answer (score 1):

[BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) has an [alpha version which supports the Touch Bar](https://www.boastr.net/second-touchbar-alpha-available/).
You can use the ‘Open Application / Script / File’ action in BTT to launch your Automator app.